# A generic error occurred in GDI+ trying upload and resize photo

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple method to create a category, and in localhost I don´t have any errors, but something strange happens in production. I get an error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CategoryId,Title,Description,Image,IsDeleted,Alt,File")] CreateCategoryViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;

        if (model.File.ContentLength > 0 && model.File != null)
        {
            var alt = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.File.FileName);
            model.Alt = alt;
            var nombreAvatar = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpeg";
            var imageAvatar = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(model.File.InputStream, true, true);
            var pathAvatar = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + nombreAvatar);
            //resize the image to the specified height and width
            using (var resized = ImageUtilities.ResizeImage(imageAvatar, 500, 410))
            {
                //save the resized image as a jpeg with a quality of 90
                ImageUtilities.SaveJpeg(pathAvatar, resized, 90);
            }

            var category = new Category
            {
                CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
                Description = model.Description,
                Image = nombreAvatar,
                Alt = model.Alt,
                IsDeleted = model.IsDeleted,
                Title = model.Title
            };

            db.CategoriesList.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I've reviewed related questions, but I don't really understand what is going wrong with the method, and I don´t understand why it works in local but throws an error in production. Can anyone explain what's happening here? Regards

Comment: Permission issues in the other environment ?

Comment: I´m using Godaddy, and I give permissions on images folder, but it still throwing issue @Shyju